# Map unique values by ID to separate columns in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have the following DataFrame:

| ID | Diagnosis | Test Result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Cancer | Positive |
| 1 | TB | Negative |
| 1 | Lupus | Indeterminate |
| 2 | Cancer | Negative |
| 2 | TB | Negative |
| 2 | Myopia | Negative |
| 2 | Hypertension | Negative |

Which is in this wide format marked by ID. I want to truncate the rows to a single entry by creating **more columns on the unique values** by each ID. I would like my DataFrame to look like:

| ID | Diagnosis_1 | Diagnosis_2 | Diagnosis_3 | Diagnosis_4 | Test Result_1 | Test Result_2 | Test Result_3 | Test Result_4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Cancer | TB | Lupus |  | Positive | Negative | Indeterminate |  |
| 2 | Cancer | TB | Myopia | Hypertension | Negative | Negative | Negative | Negative |

A couple of things to note:

- It is ok to have extra columns for IDs where the entry does not exist (see ID 1)
- The number of columns is decided by the ID with the most entries (but this may not be the same ID for each column)
- Does Pandas have a clean way to do this with some methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
In [97]: tmp = df.assign(result_num=df.groupby('ID').cumcount()+1).set_index(['ID', 'result_num']).unstack()
    ...: tmp.columns = [f'{a}_{b}' for a,b in tmp.columns]
    ...: tmp
Out[97]:
   Diagnosis_1 Diagnosis_2 Diagnosis_3   Diagnosis_4 Test Result_1 Test Result_2  Test Result_3 Test Result_4
ID
1       Cancer          TB       Lupus           NaN      Positive      Negative  Indeterminate           NaN
2       Cancer          TB      Myopia  Hypertension      Negative      Negative       Negative      Negative
```

1. assign a group serial number using `df.groupby('ID').cumcount() + 1`
2. set index to both ID and the serial number
3. then unstack the serial number column to convert it to columns
4. the last step flattens the multi-indexed column labels
5. you can add a `.fillna('')` to get rid of the `NaN`s

Comment: This is just a perfect answer. Concise and exactly what I was looking for!